# How to call API after 5 sec using RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to call another API(2) after API(1) response. And I want the other API (2) to be called after 5 seconds and stop when the condition is correct.

I started doing this and it works. But now, I want call API2 after 5 second and the initial value doesn't wait.

```
const iterator = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

return this.api1.post(data).pipe(
  concatMap((res) =>
    iterator.pipe(
      mergeMap((i) =>
        this.api2
          .get(res?.id)
          .pipe(
            tap((result: any) => {
              if (
                result.info?.count <= 7 &&
                result.done === false &&
                !isNotNullOrUndefined(result.error)
              ) {
                iterator.next(i + 1);
              } else {
                const errorsDetails = {
                  message: result.info?.stage_message,
                  detail: result.error?.details,
                };
                this.showToastError(errorsDetails, false);
              }
            }),
            takeWhile(
              (d) =>
                d.info?.count <= 7 &&
                d.done === false &&
                !isNotNullOrUndefined(d.error),
              true
            )
          )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Do you have any idea how to do it please?

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` for making the API call after 5 seconds or whatever. I would suggest learning about rxJs operators for this.

Comment: have a look to [RxJs decision tree](https://rxjs.dev/operator-decision-tree)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the request to be delayed by 5s you'll have to subscribe to it after 5s. There are obviously many ways to do this in RxJS.

You can use `timer()` and map its respone to the request:

```
timer(5000).pipe(mergeMap(() => this.api2.get(...)))
```

Or use `concat()`:

```
concat(timer(5000), this.api2.get(...))
```